# The application is not able to load applicationContent.xml. Why?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying a spring in which i tried to print name property of Student class using javabeans 
like

```
<bean id="studentbean" class="spring1.Student">  
<property name="name" value="krishna kant"></property>  
</bean>
```

here is an image of what i have

[image]

but when i try to run it says: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContent.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContent.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:61)
    at spring1.Test.main(Test.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContent.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 4 more
```

There are some other questions having the same error but i couldn't relate those questions to mine. Help me find what I am doing wrong.

```
//------------------Test.java-------------------
package spring1;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  

public class Test {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContent.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  

    Student student=(Student)factory.getBean("studentbean");  
    student.displayInfo();  
}  
}
---------------------Student.java------------------------
package spring1;

public class Student {  
private String name;  

public String getName() {  
    return name;  
}  

public void setName(String name) {  
    this.name = name;  
}  

public void displayInfo(){  
    System.out.println("Hello: "+name);  
}  
}


---------------------applicationContent.xml--------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="studentbean" class="spring1.Student">  
<property name="name" value="krishna kant"></property>  
</bean>  

</beans>
```

Comment: There is no `applicationContext.xml` there is an `spring1/applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I was thinking the same. :)

Comment: yeah i got it, it is working now @M.Deinum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try spring1/applicationContent.xml instead of applicationContent.xml because your applicationContent.xml resides in spring1

Comment: I think it is all about content vs context.

Answer (score 1):

Well what immediately jumps in my eye is that your XML-File on your screenshot is named "applicationContent.xml" and your error message can't find a file named "applicationContext.xml", which indeed, does not exist.

Comment: yeah that is my question if it exists then why i got the error it doesn't exist

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. What I'm suggesting is that you did a typo in your code and are trying to parse from a file which doesn't exist, which is why you get the error that it doesn't exist. Look closely at your actual filename and the search string in your error message: one says "applicationConte N t.xml" the other says "applicationConte X t.xml" (content vs context) and the file "applicationContext" which you are trying to parse doesn't exist, only a file "applicationContent".

Comment: I am getting the same error even after changing the name from applicationContext.xml to applicationContent.xml

Comment: Then I'm afraid we'll need some more information concerning what exactly your code is doing. Maybe provide us with a minimal reproducible example?